# Shortest Paths (all) between Source and Destination vertex

Tags: algorithm, graph

Given an undirected graph (G) with edge weights. How do I find all possible shortest paths from source to destination.
I cannot modify Dijkstra's algo, but allowed to use it as a procedure by providing inputs.

My first approach was to run Dijkstra's; extract the 1st set of shortest paths and then rip these edges from the graph and run Dijkstra's again. We run this until a path from source to destination does not change from every run of Dijkstra's

Is there a better approach ?

Comment: For "dense graphs" (many edges): floyd-warshall (O(|V|^3)), for sparse: (|V| times) Dijkstra (O(V*(V*log(V)+E)??)..i learned)

Comment: can you describe this approach to achieve this runtime ?

Comment: Your approach works only if "all possible shortest paths" means all paths that do not share any edges.

Comment: An overview with links: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#All-pairs_shortest_paths

Answer (score 0):

You should run Dijkstra only once. This executation will set the minimum cost to reach each vertice.

After that, you can run a simple DFS (backtracking) from source to destination. But using only edges (v,u,c) that  cost[v]+c==cost[u].